# What could cause an element's visual and interactive components to be rendered in a different place inside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, mobile-safari

I'm rendering a react app inside an iFrame that is using iframe-resizer and on some browsers (most notably, Safari on iOS), the elements' visual component and their interactive components get rendered in a different place. The screenshot below shows what I mean, the gray box is the iOS "input focus highlight" that occurs when you tap an input element, as you can see it's in a completely different place s the element itself (the large textarea element, labeled as "Message Pour ...")

[image: iOS Screenshot, obfuscated]

I have no idea where to even begin, I'm either searching the wrong terms or this issue is not very common, either way it looks like a browser rendering bug to me. Is there something that can be done about it, or does anyone have any clues as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this was the actual cause of the problem or not, but when I disabled all javascript scrolling if the app was running in an iframe it seemed to stop. I used `window.postMessage( ... )` and sent a `"scroll_top"` message up to the parent window to scroll instead, having this feature already available with the embed code we provide for this app. Hopefully this helps anyone else having this problem.

We were using [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) as well, if that matters.

This still seems like a rendering bug to me, but at least now it isn't happening anymore.